# GridDb grouping on particular column

Tags: griddb

Trying to write a group by query in Java client,

As [here](https://griddb.org/docs-en/manuals/GridDB_SQL_Reference.html) it says I should be use like this,

```
GROUP BY column_name_1 [, column_name_2 …]
```

So I have tried this,

```
Collection<String, Person> col = store.putCollection("col01", Person.class);
Query<Person> query = col.query("SELECT name FROM col01 GROUP BY name", Person.class);
```

and get this error:

> ```
> [151001:TQ_SYNTAX_ERROR_EXECUTION] Syntax error during parse:
> ```

Then I check [this](https://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v4_0_3/GridDB_ProgrammingTutorial.html), and it says:

> Fetching of all Columns (*) and aggregate operations (e.g., SUM) are
> available for a select expression. (Fetching of a particular Column is
> not available.)

How can I write a valid group by query?